# Derive a formula for the number of small square base pyramids required to create a bigger pyramid?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, puzzle, pattern-recognition

To quote from the problem statement:

*"Pyramids are built using smallest pyramids of "level 1", that are used as building blocks for higher levels. Stacking pyramids of "level 1" to create higher-level structures, leave gaps. Special parts, called "Tringus", are used to cover these gaps. They are of triangular shape to perfectly fill the gaps on pyramid sides."*

Here is an image to help:

[image]

**Explanation for this** : *"a pyramid of "Level 2" is constructed as follows: We are using a total of 6 pyramids of "level 1" (see the picture above). That leaves 4 gaps at the sides and we need 4 "Tringus" to fill them. In total 10 pieces."*

Now I do understand the number of parts required for n<sup>th</sup> level.

For Level 3, according to me, we have **9** (3*3) Level 1 triangles at the base.Then **4**(2*2) inverted trianlges on the base and then just keep the "Level 2" triangle on it. That gives = `9 + 4 + 6`(number of level 1 triangles used in level 2 as shown in the image) = **19**. And the number of *tringus* required will be **3** on each face so `3*4=12`. So total `19+12 = 31`.

What I am unable to do is derive a general formula for number of **total** parts required for the k<sup>th</sup> level. Any help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compute the volume of a tringus in units of a pyramid to count the number of tringuses in each layer.  The size $2$ pyramid has a volume of $8$.  There are $6$ size $1$ pyramids in a size $2$ pyramid, so a tringus has a volume of $1/2$.  Now we count the pyramids in a size $n$ pyramid
Upright pyramids-at level $k$ you have $k^2$ of them
Inverted pyramids-at level $k$ you have $(k-1)^2$ of them
Total pyramids $= \sum_{k=1}^n(k^2+(k-1)^2)=\frac 16(n(n+1)(2n+1)+(n-1)n(2n-1))=\frac 13(2n^3+n)$
The total volume is $n^3$, so the volume of tringuses is $\frac 13(n^3-n)$ and the number is $\frac 23(n^3-n)$.
The total number of pieces is $\frac 13(4n^3-n)$

Added: If you want to leave holes in the interior, just filling the openings on the faces, you will have $\frac12n(n−1)$ tringuses on each face, so $2n(n−1)$ total and the number of total pieces becomes $\frac13(2n3+n)+2n(n−1)$ This gives $31$ for $n=3$

Comment: For `n=3` you get **35** but it should be **31** as explained in the question.

Comment: I don't think so.  If you want the pyramid to be solid, you need some tringuses inside, not just on the faces.  If you want to leave holes, you will have $\frac 12 n(n-1)$ tringuses on each face, so $2n(n-1)$ total and the number of total pieces becomes $\frac 13(2n^3+n)+2n(n-1)$  This gives $31$ for $n=3$

Comment: _"They(tringus) are of triangular shape to perfectly fill the gaps on pyramid **sides**."_  I think they are just to fill the gaps on the faces.

Comment: Thanks! Please add the last line of your comment to your answer.